How to get access token without using clientId and clientSecret in .Net 4.5 application?
I have to use the REST API with .Net framework 4 and 4.5. My applications are hosted both in Azure ( as app service) and on Azure VM.
I know there Azure has a concept of managed identity. However, I'm trying to implement fetching secrets from Azure Key vault using REST API. The applications are using .Net framework 4 and 4.5.
The code is as below:
    string keyVaultUrl = "https://KeyVault.vault.azure.net";
    string secretName = "Test";
   
    string tenantId = "tenantId"; 
    string clientId = "clientId";  
    string clientSecret = "clientSecret Vaule "; 

I'm getting a access token by calling a custom method as below:
 string accessToken = await GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

The above code works fine.
For me, it's like fetching one secret from the Key vault by exposing another secret.
I have seen lots of post says using "managed identity". As I said earlier, I have to use the REST API with .Net framework 4 and 4.5. My applications are hosted both in Azure ( as app service) and on Azure VM. I believe in this case "managed identity" is not applicable - specifically when it comes to REST and .Net 4/.net 4.5 and when application does not supports required Key vault and Entra ID related namespace ( e.g. key vault "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" namespace.)
My question is what is the best ways to store "clientSecret" as its getting used to fetch the secrets from Key vault ? Where can I store the client "clientSecret" and use in the code?

You can make use of interactive flow which do not need client secret to generate access token

You can do it by marking the application as public which does not require secret

As far as i know, the common method is to store secrets, such as the secret to access the key vault, in environment variables and then accessing the env-vars through your code.
Is this helpfull?

I think, this is not the best practice. Is there any Microsoft official documentation? Please share.

Sure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/secrets-best-practices#avoid-hardcoding-secrets


Note that: ClientID is mandatory to generate access token, if you do not want to make use of client secret then you can generate access token using Interactive flow or Username/Password flow.

For an application to make it as Public you need to set Allow public client flows as YES:

But according to Microsoft Username/Password flow is not recommended due to security issues.
class Program
{
    private const string TenantId = "your-tenant-id"; 
    private const string ClientId = "your-client-id"; 
    private const string Resource = "https://vault.azure.net"; 

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string username = "user@yourdomain.com"; 
        string password = "yourpassword"; 

        try
        {
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                .WithTenantId(TenantId)
                .Build();

            var securePassword = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }

            var result = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(
                new[] { $"{Resource}/.default" },
                username,
                securePassword)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Access Token: " + result.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

You can also make use of InteractiveBrowserCredential flow which do not need client secret:
class Program
{
    private const string ClientId = "ClientID"; 
    private const string TenantId = "TenantID"; 
    private const string Resource = "https://vault.azure.net";

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            TenantId = TenantId
        });

        var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { $"{Resource}/.default" });

        var token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

        Console.WriteLine("Access Token: " + token.Token);
    }
}


If the above does not resolve the issue, then you have to Store the clientSecret in environment variables. This is a simple method and keeps sensitive data out of your codebase as suggested by Provadis.
string clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("YourClientSecretEnvironmentVariable");


OR use a separate method to fetch the clientSecret before using it to obtain the access token.

string clientSecret = await GetSecretFromKeyVault(keyVaultUrl, "YourClientSecretName");
string accessToken = await GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

